# Typo in the FAQ list

Tags: bug, status-completed

[The FAQ list](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/faq#what-notation-and-symbols-are-commonly-used-here) reads, in part:

> Some basics for people new to LaTeX. Inline formulas are surrounded by single dollar signs (`f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c` renders as $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$), and block formulas by double dollar signs so that `x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac} }{2a}` renders as

That should be:

> Some basics for people new to LaTeX. Inline formulas are surrounded by single dollar signs (`$f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$` renders as $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$), and block formulas by double dollar signs so that `$$ x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac} }{2a} $$` renders as

with dollar signs. (Part of the point of the sentence is to distinguish between `$` and `$$`, so they should be in the examples.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Fixed](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/revisions/619/5). Thanks for the headsup! :)

Comment: Hm, the change doesn't seem to have promulgated to the `/faq` page yet. Does that happen in a nightly script or something? I thought it was immediate.

Comment: @msh210: Not sure. For me, it shows the new version, but not if I view it while logged out (from incognito).  I guess there's a small delay.

Comment: Ah, there we go. Good now.